# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, TarFile found

Tags: python, tar

I get the following error....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploycommerce.py", line 56, in <module>
    if tarfile.is_tarfile(optfile):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2587, in is_tarfile
    t = open(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1658, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1720, in gzopen
    fileobj = bltn_open(name, mode + "b")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, TarFile found
```

when I try to fun the following...

```
optfile = tarfile.open(opt_tar_input,"r:gz")
# ERROR THROWN IN FOLLOWING...
if tarfile.is_tarfile(optfile):
    # extract all contents
    test =""
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tarfile.is_tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html?highlight=tarfile.is_tarfile#tarfile.is_tarfile) takes the *name* of a file, not the file object.

If you've successfully called `tarfile.open` then the path pointed to a tarfile.

Note that the usual Python coding style would be

```
try:
    optfile = tarfile.open(...)
except tarfile.ReadError:
    # not a tarfile
```

This is usually summarised in the slogan "[it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)".

Answer (score 0):

`tarfile.is_tarfile` takes a file name, not `TarFile` object. The check is redundant anyway —if it wasn't a tar file, `tarfile.open` would raise an exception.